# Asymptotically Stable?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following system : $\quad x_{1} ' = x_{1} - 3x_{2} + x_{1}^{3}\quad$ and
$\quad x_{2} ' = -x_{1} + x_{2} - x_{2} ^ {2}.\quad$
I want to determine the stability of the equilibrium point : origin of the above system using Lyapunov Function.

My effort: Since there is no straightforward method known to me, to find Lyapunov function, I tried with
a) $x_{1}^{2} + x_{1}^{2}x_{2}^{2} + x_{2}^{2} $

b) $x_{1}^{4} + x_{2}^{4}$

c) $ \frac{3}{2} x_{2}^{2} + \frac{1}{2} x_{1}^{2}$

d) $x_{1}^{2} +  x_{2}^{2}$

But there was no conclusion with these functions..... So, please help me out of it!!

Comment: Is the problem asking you to do it this way, that is by using a LF? Sometimes you cannot find a LF and have to resort to other approaches.

Comment: @ Amzoti, Actually I am solving the problems from the book by Perko...In the exercise this problem appears... & they have asked to use Lyapunov function..Apart from the first problem till now I am unable to solve the other three!!

Answer (score 2):

The linear part of your system is $\dot{x}_1=x_1-3x_2$ and $\dot{x}_2=-x_1+x_2$.
One of the eigenvalues is $\dfrac{2+\sqrt{12}}{2}$ which has a positive real part.
It follows that the linear part is unstable, and so does the nonlinear system.

Comment: That is true Said Naciri.... But can you construct a Lyapunov function for that???

Comment: A Lyapunov function does exist in such a case. Indeed, asymptotic stability is equivalent to the existence of a Lyapunov function.

Comment: @ Saïd Naciri .. But unstability can also be concluded from Lyapunov Function.. (i.e. if $V'(x,t) \gt {0}$ )... Isn't it??

Comment: The term Lyapunov function is used only if $\dot{V}<0$.

Comment: If $\dot{V}\leq 0$ then $V$ is said to be a weak Lyapunov function.

Comment: But you can find such a function! You should try to diagonalize the matrix by an orthogonal change of basis Q!